# Fill array with elements from another array

Tags: java, arrays, element, fill

Hey I would like to fill an array from elements from another array.
For example (below)
And array b should be filled with elements in this order from array b. 
Is there some method for this? I only know Arrays.fill ( but it's for 1 element).
The table a is variable, not static !

```
int a[1,2,3,4];

int b[] = new int[100];
int b[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...}
```

Comment: you want to repeat a in b N time is that what you want?

Comment: No.Fill b with a elements to b.lenth.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.arraycopy()` method. Which copies a source array from a specific beginning position to the destination array from the mentioned position.

e.g. copy array a 25 times to fill in b.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i += a.length) {
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, i, 4);
}
```

Comment: This will throw and exception if the length of "b" is not evenly divisible by the length of "a".

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine a simple for loop that cycles through the first array and adds to the second would be a basic solution without invoking a method you might not be familiar with.

```
    int a[1,2,3,4];
    int b[]  = new int[100];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) 
    {
       if(j == 4) 
       { 
           j = 0; 
       }
       int n = a[j];
       b[i] = n;
       j++; 
    }
```

Or you can have it check the array length if the size of array "a" changes

```
    int a[1,2,3,4];
    int b[]  = new int[100];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) 
    {
       if(j == a.length) 
       { 
           j = 0; 
       }
       int n = a[j];
       b[i] = n;
       j++; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with Streams

```
int b[] = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i == a.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1)
            .limit(100)
            .mapToInt(i -> a[i])
            .toArray();
```

`Stream.iterate(0, i -> i == a.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1)`:
Starts with 0 as the seed and produces a stream of Integers incrementally. We reset/restart once the index reaches the end of the array.

`limit(100)`: Limit to 100 elements as the source of the Stream is infinite.

`.mapToInt(i -> a[i])`: Convert the incoming Integer *index* to an int by getting the element at the *index* from array *a*.

`.toArray()`: Collect the individual elements to an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a for loop and the modulus operator:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i ++) {
        b[i] = a[i % a.length];
    }
```